# Open pdf file from jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to open a pdf file using `ServletOutputStream` in JSP. The code is:

```
response.setContentLength(statementVO.getOutputStream().size());
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(statementVO.getOutputStream().toByteArray());
out.flush();
out.close();
```

I am getting the following error

```
WAS 6.0 - Response already committed / OutputStream already obtained
```

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because you're using a JSP file instead of a Java class to write Java code in. The JSP file is intented to serve template text like HTML/CSS/JS and so on. The JSP implicitly uses [`response.getWriter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) to write template text. Whenever you call [`response.getOutputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29) inside a JSP, you risk getting this error because you cannot open **both** the `Writer` and the `OutputStream`. You can only open the one or the other, see also the linked javadocs.

To solve this problem there are basically 2 solutions:

1. Do this in a real Java class instead of a JSP file. A Servlet class is the best suitable place for this. You can find [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html) a basic example.
2. Remove all template text (this includes whitespace and newlines!) from JSP file so that it doesn't implicitly call `response.getWriter()`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829064/return-tiff-file-from-outputstream-on-jsp) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send pdf file as response everytime, its better to use servlet instead of jsp. But if it's conditional state, you must send your response conditional! you can not write to response twice.